# How to get count of results returned by a query - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As simple as it may sound:

I have a SQL query using SSMS 2014.

```
SELECT  *
FROM RAWRESULTS
GROUP BY Code
```

This returns 2282 results. I want to modify the query to return 1 result with value 2282.

I have tried:

```
SELECT  Count(*)
FROM RAWRESULTS
GROUP BY Code

SELECT  TOP 1 @@ROWCOUNT
FROM RAWRESULTS
GROUP BY Code
```

Second option does not give consistent results. It randomly returns 1 instead of 2282.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from rawresults
```

That will give you a count of all records from rawresults table

```
select count(distinct code) from rawresults
```

That will give you a count of distinct codes from rawresults

```
select code, count(*) from rawresults group by code
```

That will give you a count of each code

Comment: thanks for that. Just running all three here are the results: 1) Will give 5272 thats because I am not grouping by anything. Not my requirement. 3) Would return 2282 rows thats not my requirement. I just need 1 row returned with 2282. 2) This is probably the solution:  As it returns 1 row with 2282.

Comment: Excellent. So  basically you were looking to count how many distinct codes you had in rawresults. 2nd query will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY This** you can achieve that by using subquery as you want the total records returns grouping by code in a single row:

```
select count(*) totalCount from (
select count(*) groupCountofEachCode from rawresults group by code) t
```